# Copy cell value from one column to another if condition met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

How can I make a macro which looks if Column F equals to "dept1"and if it's true, copy value from column D to E.

This is what I've tried but it copies the entire row.

```
    Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

With rng1
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criterial:="GH"
   Range("D2:D700").Copy
    Range("E2:E700").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

[image]

Comment: `Range("D2:D700").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`?

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values Using `Worksheet.Evaluate`

- The basic thing you're missing here is that **you cannot copy a range to a discontinuous range** (even if it is of the same size) e.g. the range could be `"A2:F4,A7:F9,A11:F11"`. Now when you use `"D2:D700"` properly with `Intersect`, it will grab `"D2:D4,D7:D9,D11"` but this can only be copied to a continuous range e.g. `"E2:E8"` (you would like it to copy to `"E2:E4,E7:E9,E11"`).
- `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is useful e.g. when you want to copy the filtered rows (one below the other) to another worksheet e.g. from `"A2:F4,A7:F9,A11:F11"` in `Sheet1` to `"A2"` in `Sheet2` which will fill the range `"A2:F8"`.

**Simple**

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude header row
    End With
    
    ' e.g.: IF(F2:F21="Dept1",D2:D21,"")
    Dim EvalString As String: EvalString = "IF(" _
        & rg.Columns(6).Address & "=""Dept1""," _
        & rg.Columns(4).Address & ","""")"
        
    rg.Columns(5).Value = ws.Evaluate(EvalString)
    
End Sub
```

**Using Constants**

```vb
Sub CopyDataConstants()

    Const SourceColumn As Long = 4
    Const ResultColumn As Long = 5
    Const CriteriaColumn As Long = 6
    Const CriteriaString As String = "Dept1"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude header row
    End With
    
    ' e.g.: IF(F2:F21="Dept1",D2:D21,"")
    Dim EvalString As String: EvalString = "IF(" _
        & rg.Columns(CriteriaColumn).Address & "=""" & CriteriaString & """," _
        & rg.Columns(SourceColumn).Address & ","""")"
        
    rg.Columns(ResultColumn).Value = ws.Evaluate(EvalString)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, ive tried both examples and they work but it clears out cells of column E if it doesn't match "Dept1". is there a way to prevent that?  Ill attach a screenshot on the question if it helps.

Comment: That's an easy fix: replace `& ","""")"` with `& "," & rg.Columns(5).Address & ")"` in the 1st procedure, and with `& "," & rg.Columns(ResultColumn).Address & ")"` in the 2nd procedure.